# onClick event only works when position:fixed;

Tags: javascript, css

I am adding `onclick="alert('test');"` to the DIV DOM elements I am creating and the onclick event does not work unless I change the positioning for the entire document to fixed.

I have tried adding the trigger manually and firing using click(). I have tried adding the click event to all the child elements. I tried using addEvenListener(). I tried to change the positioning of just the div and it's child elements. None of these configurations make any difference. I can only get the click event to function when I set the position for the entire document to fixed. I pasted below the portion for the CSS that formats the entire document, and I pasted the class I am using to generate the HTML code. I can't use positioning fixed as it won't work with the grid I created for the game, but absolute positioning works.

```
* {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
}

class Card {
    constructor(suite, value){
        this.name = `${suite.suite}${value}`;
        this.value = value;
        this.suite = suite;
        this.face = false;
        this.element = this.element.bind(this);
        this.elementParent = this.elementParent.bind(this);
        this.symbol = this.symbol.bind(this);
        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    }
    element(){
        return document.getElementById(this.name);
    }
    elementParent(){
        return this.element().parentElement;
    }
    symbol(){
        switch(this.value){
            case 11:
                 return "J";
            case 12:
                return "Q";
            case 13:
                return "K";
            case 1:
                return "A";
            default:
                return this.value;
        }
    }
    render(){
        let me = document.createElement("div");
        if(this.face){
            me.innerHTML = `<h2 class="topLeft" style="color:${this.suite.color};" onclick="alert('test')">${this.symbol()}</h3>
                        <h1 style="color:${this.suite.color};" onclick="alert('test')">${this.suite.symbol}</h3>
                        <h2 class="bottomRight" style="color:${this.suite.color};" onclick="alert('test')">${this.symbol()}</h3>`;
            me.classList.add("cardFront");
        } else {
            me.classList.add("cardBack");
        }
        me.style.position = "absolute";
        me.id = this.name;
        return me;
    }
    currentPOS(){
        return [this.element().top, this.element().left];
    }
}
```

I would like to fire a function when the DOM elements of the card are clicked.

Comment: Can you turn the code you posted into a [mcve] that we can try to run?

Comment: Well, I attempted to make a compact version and I succeeded. In the small version the click events work just fine. So there is something in the larger body of code that is interfering with the click event from functioning. Really I was just hoping for some suggestions of places to look or known situations where click events are know not to work.

Comment: After toying with the code further, I discovered the problem occurs when I nest the clickable DIV inside another DIV. Both DIVs are set to ````position:absolute;````, and the clickable DIV works when appended to the body the click event works fine, but when appended to the DIV the click event stops working.

Comment: Try giving the clickable DIV a higher `z-index`. The click may be going to the non-clickable DIV.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. I have the parent DIV ````z-index: -1;```` and the child ````z-index:2;```` and it doesn't correct the problem. I tried to replicate the problem using a fresh html and the problem went away, so there is something deeper in my code that is creating this problem. I'll keep chopping away and see if I can isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation I found a solution. I was trying to create a DOM object `let me = document.createElement("div");`, adding the click event `me.onclick = 'alert("Success!")';` and then appending it to the document `document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(me);"` and it wasn't working.

My solution was to append the DOM object to the document `document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(me);"`, then add the click event `document.getElementById("me").addEventListener("click", tryMe);`  It works like a charm now.

Now when I move DOM elements between DIVs I have to remove the `eventListener` before removing the element from the DOM, then re-add the `eventListener` after creating the element in another DIV.